# Get following of users whom I follow in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, left-join

I have two tables called `users` and `fans`.
 The `users` table looks like this:

```
id | name
---------
1  | John
2  | Mark
3  | Bill
4  | Steve
5  | Jeff
```

And this is the `fans` table:

```
fan | user
1   | 2
1   | 5
2   | 3
2   | 4
2   | 5
```

"Fan" is the user who is following the user and "user" is the one who is being followed. Now If we take John (id 1) as the current user, and given that John is following Mark (id 2), How can we get the following of everyone whom John is following, but not the ones whom John is already following (In this case John is following Mark. Mark is following user 3, 4 and 5 but only 3 and 4 should be returned because John is already following user 5.)? I tried doing this with the `IN` operator but I am not sure it would scale well with more entries. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide expect result from your sample data thanks?

Comment: What's your mysql version

Comment: The version is  5.7.34.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any data to provide but what I am expecting is that, for example if user 1 is following user 2 and user 3, I want all the users whom user 2 and user 3 is following, as a list of friends suggestion for user 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join multiple copies of `fans`:

```
SELECT f1.user
FROM fans f1 
INNER JOIN fans f2 ON f2.user = f1.fan 
LEFT JOIN fans f3 ON f3.fan = f2.fan AND f3.user = f1.user 
WHERE f2.fan = ? AND f3.fan IS NULL;
```

If you want the names of the users also:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
INNER JOIN fans f1 ON f1.user = u.ID
INNER JOIN fans f2 ON f2.user = f1.fan 
LEFT JOIN fans f3 ON f3.fan = f2.fan AND f3.user = f1.user 
WHERE f2.fan = ? AND f3.fan IS NULL;
```

Change `?` to the id of the user that you want.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e3532158d379e5bc275345e26a5eab44).

Comment: Thank you! Just want to know, will this slow down on more entries? And I think using the `DISTINCT` statement can prevent duplicates, right?

Comment: @WebDiva as long as the 2 columns of fans are properly defined as foreign keys referencing the column ID of users then they are also indexed and this speeds up the query. But of course if the tables get bigger and bigger then the query's performance will decrease. If you get duplicate rows you can add the keyword DISTINCT: `SELECT DISTINCT u.* ....`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can try to join `users` and `fans` to find who is followed user then do join

```
SELECT *
FROM users u1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM users uu
    INNER JOIN fans f
    ON uu.id = f.fan 
    WHERE uu.id = 1 AND f.user = u1.id
)
```

or using self-join user twice

```
SELECT u1.*
FROM users u1
INNER JOIN users uu
INNER JOIN fans f
ON uu.id = f.fan AND f.user = u1.id
WHERE uu.id = 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=021cfc04a88d8211f1434c21e6a9c944)